# How to parallax scroll a background image with jquery and css without plugin?

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I want to scroll a background image like the link below

http://www.littleco.com/?scrollto=Work?

i tried so many plugins but it is hard to understand is there any easy process to parallax scroll background image easily with CSS and Jquery

Comment: some css frameworks such as `Materializecss` couple parallax in their functionalities. maybe if you had used some frameworks, check out their documentation

Comment: inspect the website, check the resources, javascript and you'll find it, they don't use plugin, it's 40 lines of uncompressed code

Comment: [Here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/07/how-to-create-a-simple-parallax-effect/) you can read how you would go about creating a simple "true" parallax effect, using css and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with CSS.

Add `background-attachment: fixed;` to the div that has the background image.

Comment: This is the simplest parallax without the use of jquery or any js

Comment: Except this isn't really parallax, it's just a fixed background.